# How can I load my data file in R using command lines?

Tags: r, shell, command-line, bioinformatics, slurm

I would like to run job using R. 
I wrote r script as follow

```
#!/bin/sh
#SBATCH --time=168:00:00
#SBATCH --mem=50gb
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --job-name=StrAuto
#SBATCH --error=R.%J.err
#SBATCH --output=R.%J.out
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --mail-user=asallam@unl.edu
module load R/3.3
R CMD BATCH AF1.R
```

Then I worte the command lines in AF1.R  file as follow

```
outer(names(m[,-1]), names(m[,-1]), function(x,y){colSums((m[,x]-m[,y])**2/156854,na.rm=TRUE)})
```

Now I would like to ask how I load my data m.txt. what is the command that I should write before outer(.......

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this question about batching R or how to read some structured text file? It's a little unclear, and it would help if you make this a [reproducible question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have three files. The first file is a script of submitting the job in our computer center and this file with extension txt. The second one is r code with an extension of . R (in above it is AF1.R). This file includes the command which I would like to run in my data. The third file is my data which is m.txt.

Comment: Read the link I provided. Knowing that there is a file tells me nothing about the structure or anything else. I suggest you search for questions (here on StackOverflow) pertaining to importing files of different formats. If you really cannot find what you want (and please spend more than 5 minutes search), then read the link about generating reproducible questions. Here's another link, provided within StackOverflow help, about [minimal, verifiable examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without a little more detail, your question may be closed for being too vague.